# Few items in SharePoint list are not auto-populating in search bar

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm using a SharePoint 2013 site, in which one of the page has a search bar(which has 'autocomplete' feature). The values from the SharePoint list needs to be populated as soon as a character is typed in the drop down.
It worked fine in the beginning, but now the issue arises when a new item is added in the SharePoint list, and when we type for that in the search bar it is not getting auto-populated in the search bar.

Any help here, please!

Answer (score 0):

Verify the below:

Go to the list setting page -> Click on the Advanced Settings

Under the **search** section :

Allow items from this list to appear in search results? **Yes**

And from the **Reindex List** section, click on the **Reindex List** button

Then run the **Full Crawl** from Central Admin.

Now search should work.

Reference screenshot:

[image: Why SharePoint list item does not appear in the search?]

**Auto Complete in SharePoint search using jquery:**

```
1: // Parse an item and create an title/value dictionary with all the properties available

   2: function getFields(results) {

   3:     r = {};

   4:     for(var i = 0; i<results.length; i++) {

   5:         if(results[i] != undefined && results[i].Key != undefined) {

   6:             r[results[i].Key] = results[i].Value;

   7:         }

   8:     }

   9:     return r;

  10: }

  11:  

  12: $(document).ready(function() {

  13:     

  14:     var autocomplete = $( "#restSearch" ).autocomplete({

  15:         minLength: 3,

  16:         source: function( request, response ) {

  17:             $.ajax({

  18:                 beforeSend: function (request)

  19:                 {

  20:                     request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8");

  21:                 },

  22:                 url: "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + request.term + "*'",

  23:                 dataType: "json",

  24:                 success: function( data ) {

  25:                     response( $.map( data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results, function( item ) {

  26:                         return {

  27:                             fields: getFields(item.Cells.results)

  28:                         }

  29:                     }));

  30:                 },

  31:                 error: function( data ) {

  32:                     alert('search error');

  33:                 }

  34:             });

  35:         },

  36:         // Run this when the item is in focused (not selected)

  37:         focus: function( event, ui ) {

  38:             //$( "#restSearch" ).val(ui.item.value );

  39:             return false;

  40:         },

  41:         // Run this when the item is selected

  42:         select: function( event, ui ) {

  43:             location.href = ui.item.fields.Path;

  44:         },

  45:         appendTo: $('#menu-container')

  46:     }).data( "uiAutocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

  47:         // format the documents using the OOTB SharePoint icons

  48:         img = "ic" + item.fields.FileType + ".png";

  49:         if(item.fields.FileType == "html") {

  50:             img = "html16.png";

  51:         }

  52:         return $("<li>").append('<a><img style="margin-right:3px;top:3px;" src="/_layouts/15/images/'+ img +'">' + item.fields.Title + '</a>' )

  53:             .appendTo( ul );

  54:     };

  55: });
```

Source:

[Auto Complete in SharePoint search using jquery](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8b6c458c-6884-4daa-bc69-19827cf82828/auto-complete-in-sharepoint-search-using-jquery?forum=sharepointsearch)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The code is working fine, I re-indexed the list. My concern is auto-complete is not working only for few items(probably newly added items in the list)